How do I get over a Firebase rules problem I'm having when I think my user configurations should allow read/write
I am logged into my app using GoogleAuthProvider and into my browser as joethetest@gmail.com

My app project rules looks like this

On a view I have a toggle that triggers a setDoc

When I use that toggle I get this message in my console

Ultimately I’d like several roles for users in the app but I am unsure how to approach setting up the permissions.
I found this blog post but it seems like overkill, I just want joethetest to be able to use that setDoc.

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Those users in the first screenshots are the collaborators who have access to your Firebase project. That's completely separate from signing users in to Firebase Authentication in your application code.

"I’d like several roles for users in the app but I am unsure how to approach setting up the permissions" See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

@DougStevenson thank you for this advice, I used photos due to the syntax highlighting that helps when reviewing code

@FrankvanPuffelen yes, i was realizing this, thank you for your response

@RenaudTarnec thank you for pointing out this documentation resource, it will help when it comes time to implement my user role based permissions/access

@BrandonScott If you think it helps to show a picture of code, then show both the picture and copy the text into the question.  Stack Overflow is very specific about this and has been discussed thoroughly.  You don't really have a special case here.  Read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

The rules work with Firebase users and Firestore data. In your screenshot, you show "developers" or other people you personally know and have access to your Firebase/GCP project.
To find the actual Firebase user, you need to click on the Authentication side panel (see image). 
Users appear there when your app has some signup/login process. After those users exist, you can decide if you want roles stored in the JWT, or if you make a separate collection that stores user roles. As soon as you have data in the JWT or inside the Database, you can access it via rules.
